# "Network Request Failed"

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to grab info from: http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo to display in my app but I keep on getting a "Network Request Failed" error.

I am literally copying and pasting (well i've edited the params a bit of things so that the earthquake data can be taken) the code from Facebook's React Native Movies tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/sample-application-movies.html#final-source-code) and replacing

```
var REQUEST_URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/docs/MoviesExample.json'
```

with

```
var REQUEST_URL = 'http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo'
```

I have already changed info.plist to allow like everything possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the demo account as you have specified in the link?. If so you need to sign in and enable free webservice for your account to get things to work.